# cannot find symbol syntax error while building through maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, build, syntax

Why my build failing saying cannot find symbol?

[image]

Code 1

```
    public String getAzureUserName() {
        return "user123";
    }
 
    public String getAzurePassword() {
        return "dfdfdfdf";
    }

public String toString() {

    return "RepositoryEnv [gitVendor=" + gitVendor + ", gitUserName=" + gitUserName + ", gitPassword=" + gitPassword + ", gitAzureUserName=" + gitAzureUserName + ", gitAzurePassword=" + gitAzurePassword
            + "]";
}
```

Code 2

```
String aAzureUsername= aRepoEnv.getAzureUserName();
    String aAzurePassword = aRepoEnv.getAzurePassword();

(ApplicationBuilderConstants.azurerepos.equalsIgnoreCase(aRepoType)) {

                                                          String azureListApiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/" + aAzureUsername + "/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0";
                                                          String azureRepoApiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/" + aAzureUsername + "/" + aAppRequest.getProjectName()  + "/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0";
                                                                                     
                                                          List<String> projList = new ArrayList<>();
                                                          String plainCreds = aAzureUsername + ":" + aAzurePassword;
                                                          byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
                                                          String base64Creds = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCredsBytes));
                                                          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                                                          headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
                                                          HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
                                                          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Comment: Presumably because you didn't declare that variable anywhere.  Or maybe it went out of scope.  Hard to tell from this tiny snippet of your code.

Comment: update the code